# Find 10 largest tuples according to its first value

Tags: python, tuples

Sorry for the wording, by largest tuple I mean the first value in the tuple is large.

```
    AccuList = list()
    Result = tuple()
    for V in itertools.combinations(variable_list, 5):
            variable_to_use = list(V)
            for i in range(0,100):
                Accuracy = #some code to calculate
                AccuList.append(Accuracy)
            #Mean    
            M = np.mean(AccuList)
            #Std
            D = np.std(AccuList,ddof=1)
            Result = (M,D, variable_to_use)
```

I want to find 10 'Result' tuples with 10 largest M
Ranking the tuples by only the M value in it.
If I need a for loop to achieve this, where should the for loop be(where to indent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's save the results:

```
acculist = []
# no need to define `result = tuple()` here.
result_list = []  # make a list to store results in

for v in itertools.combinations(variable_list, 5):
    for i in range(0, 100):
        ...
    m = np.mean(acculist)
    d = np.std(acculist, ddof=1)
    result = (m, d, list(v))
    result_list.append(result)  # add each result to the list
```

Then sort the list. Tuples already sort by first element (then second, then third, ..., then nth) so we'll just have to reverse the order to get a descending sort instead of an ascending sort.

```
result_list.sort(reverse=True)  # descending instead of ascending
```

and slice off the first ten items

```
top_ten = result_list[:10]
```

Comment: Another way is to use normal sort order and pick the last ten elements as: `top_ten = result_list[-10:]`. Not that it matters more than a few key strokes. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that I forgot tuples are compared in element order.

Comment: @JohanL hmm yes, I've spent too much time in Haskell lately and it *would* matter there (sort reverse -> slice front only processes 10 elements, while sort standard -> slice back processes n-10 elements)

Comment: @AdamSmith Lazy Evaluation FTW! :-)

Comment: @Dylan if they weren't, or you were comparing some custom object, all the stdlib sorts accept a `key` keyword argument that accepts a function to select the right field, i.e. `sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda t: t[2])` to compare on the 3rd element of each tuple in `list_of_tuples`

Comment: You don't need to sort, because you don't care about the order of the last *n* - 10 items. Create a heap in O(n) time, then pop 10 items. The total running time is O(n) vs O(n lg n) to sort the entire list. (Each pop is an O(lg n) operation, but a *constant* number of pops still only takes O(lg n) overall, which is negligible compared to the O(n) cost of building the heap in the first place.)

Comment: @chepner agreed, but explaining a heap to someone I'm judging to be a relative beginner seemed like more work than O(n lg n) :)

Comment: The standard library provides a heap implementation; it's two lines of code to get the required items.

Comment: @chepner I didn't mean it would take more effort to write the heap, I meant it would take more effort to make it obviously correct to a relative beginner. "Why do I use a heap instead of a list?" "Why can't I append to this heap now?" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add your elements to a heap, the pop the 10 smallest items from the heap. The `heapq` module in the standard library makes this particularly simple.

```
import heapq

results = []
for V in itertools.combinations(variable_list, 5):
    variable_to_use = list(V)
    accu_list = [ ... for i in range(100)]
    m = np.mean(accu_list)
    d = np.std(accu_list, ddof=1)
    results.append((m, d, variable_to_use))

heapq.heapify(results)
ten_largest = heapq.nlargest(10, results)
```

This is significantly faster than sorting. Creating the heap given all the items up front takes only `O(n)` time, while sorting takes `O(n lg n)` time. Taking a *constant* number of elements from the heap takes only an additional `O(lg n)` time, so the overall complexity is still `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you for providing another solution. I tried this one, however the time used to run the above code is the same as the first method. Maybe there is something wrong in my code ?

Comment: The overall running time may be dominated by the time it takes to build `results` in the first place.